# Can not read connection string from Settings.settings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dataadapter, oracle-client

I have created application in Visual Studio 2013. For connection database and reading data i am using dataset which read connection string from Settings.settings file. Everything working in visual studio 2013. But when i opened this project in visual studio 2017 i cant create new adapter or configure it.  I posted following errors below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i solve this problem? Is it visual studio 2017's bug or i should update some packages?

Comment: Check your app.config. There should be connection string settings in there for your xsd

Comment: @Wheels73 here is my connection string in app.config file

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Db.Properties.Settings.cs" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=emon;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=QUETZALCOATLUS"
      providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: OK. so do you still have a project called "Db"? And do you have a settings file in that project?